# If I have a k-dimensional random vector distributed as multivariate gaussian, are the elements of the random vector also gaussian?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Suppose I have a $k$-dimensional random vector $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$, where $\mu$ is the mean vector and $\Sigma$ the covariance matrix.

Is the $i$-th element of $X$ also distributed as a gaussian with $X_i \sim N(\mu_i,\Sigma_{ii})$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A random vector $X$ have the multinormal distribution if **all linear combinations** are normally distributed. Just take the linear combination with coefficient vector $e_i = (0,0,\dots, 1,0,\dots,0)$ where the one is in place $i$. Then $e_i^T X=X_i$, the $i$th component, hence that is normally distributed.

For the additional question in the comments about mean and variance of $X_i$.
For the expectation (mean) of a linear combination we have 
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}  \E \sum_i a_i X_i = \sum_i a_i \E X_i = \sum_i a_i \mu_i
$$
and then you an conclude using the above!

For the variance of a linear combination, use that the covariance of linear combinations are given by
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Cov}{Cov} 
\Cov(\sum_i a_i X_i, \sum_j b_j Y_j) = \sum_i \sum_j a_i b_j \Cov(X_i,Y_j)
$$
then that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}
\Var(\sum_i a_i X_i)=\Cov(\sum_i a_i X_i, \sum_j a_j X_j)=
\sum_i \sum_j a_i a_j \Cov(X_i, X_j)
$$
finally putting the coefficient vector $e_i$ into this formulas.

So, we are using that expectation is a linear operator, while covariance is a bilinear operator.

Comment: More generally, any _subset_ of the $n$ variables has a multinormal distribution because linear combinations of the random variables in the subset are also linear combinations of the $n$ random variables (it's just that some coefficients are $0$), and hence are normally distributed too. The mean vector and covariance matrix are subvector and submatrix of $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This shows that $X_i$ is normally distributed. But what about its mean and variance? Can you show that these are $\mu_i$ and $\Sigma_{ii}$? (what Zachary Blumenfeld claims to be correct)

Comment: @kjetil, +1 nice answer! Small typo in the end, I assume you mean "a linear" not "alinear".

Comment: Concerning the expectation, perhaps I'm missing something, but wouldn't the last line $\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}  \sum_i a_i \E X_i = \sum_i a_i \mu_i$ assume that $\E X_i = \mu_i$ and is in fact not a proof that this is the case? Inspired by what you've written, Id say $\E X_i = \E e_i^T X = e_i^T \E X = e_i^T \mu = \mu_i$ would be a proof, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 3):

[kjetil's answer (+1)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/175742/1352) addresses the more general case of *linear combinations* of components of your multivariate normal distribution.

Your specific case concerns the so-called [*marginals* of the multivariate normal distribution](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=marginals+of+the+multivariate+normal+distribution). And yes, [the marginals of a multivariate normal distribution are again normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Marginal_distributions) (multivariate normal, if you look at higher-dimensional marginals than your one-dimensional ones).

Interestingly, and importantly, the converse does *not* hold. A multivariate distribution can have normal marginals, but be non-multivariate normal. This is a standard homework problem. See, e.g., [Kowalski (1973, *The American Statistician*)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2683630?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), or [here](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/48-example-nonnormal-bivariate-distribution-normal-marginals-let-x1--n-0-1-let-show-follow-q6675271).

This indicates the importance of the "**all**" in kjetil's answer - it's not enough for only *some* linear combinations of marginals to be normal, *all* linear combinations need to be normal for the whole vector to be multivariate normal.